# Dataflow in Eclipse: Cannot run program "gcloud"

Tags: eclipse, macos, google-cloud-dataflow

When running the Dataflow starter example in Eclipse I get the error:

```
 Cannot run program "gcloud": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I have already installed gcloud and it's in my PATH - it runs from the command line.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse go to `Run -> Run configurations... -> Service -> Environment` and add a variable called `PATH` there. If you don't know your current path, go to the command line and type `echo $PATH`.